# Enable kernel's net_key, inet_esp, crypto_hmac modules for to use in a VPN

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I'm trying to turn on modules for VPN so I followed [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1351701)   to compile new ubuntu kernel 3.8.6 .
But the features I've turned on using `make menuconfig` seem not to be enabled. 
(the features I want : `net_key`, `inet_esp`, `crypto_hmac`, etc..)

I've tried to make `gre` tunnel which modules are not loaded automatically by editing `/etc/rc.local` and adding `modprobe ip_gre` so it would start after reboot.

My questions are:

1. How to check the VPN features I've enabled using `menuconfig` are truly enabled?
2. Is it possilbe to enable the modules manually (like `ip_gre`) by editing `rc.local`?

I'm using Ubuntu server 12.04 on VBOX 4.2.10

Answer (score 0):

About first question: to make sure that the option is active in running kernel, you can use `zgrep` to filter lines from `/proc/config.gz`:

```
$ zgrep CONFIG_HMAC /proc/config.gz
```

My result is `CONFIG_CRYPTO_HMAC=y`.

Second question: the right way to make a module to load when starting is to insert it's name in right config file (depending on your distro that might be modprobe config, or something like `/etc/modules` or a file in `/etc/modules-load.d/`, containing the module name). Modprobe config allows you to use additional module parameters if you need to, blacklisting some modules and so on.

Comment: You have to press shift-enter to insert a line feed in your comment.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply . 
the result after i tried zgrep is 
gzip: /proc/config.gz : no such file or directory . 
is it because something wrong with my new kernel because i was not compiled it properly ??? @TNW

Comment: Seems that you haven't checked the option to generate /proc/config.gz during your kernel configuration or you're still running your old kernel. Are you sure that the kernel you're using is the one you compiled? You can use `uname -a` to check whether it's right version and such. Did you complete the tutorial?

Comment: maybe just like you said, i haven't generated  /proc/confing.gz in configuration. `uname -a` command show it is the right kernel . it shows Linux ubuntu 3.8.6 . that's mean i have to recompile it again?

Comment: i just browse kernel configuration. that option you mentioned is not checked. is it possible to compile just that part? it took 2 hours for me to compile full kernel

Comment: If you're sure that it's the right kernel then it's probably not worth it. What makes you think that these features are disabled, though?

Comment: because the ipsec modules don't show up on `lsmod` command. so i thought it just same like `ip_gre` module which is need to be enabled manually. if it is the right kernel, so there's a high possibility that the ipsecs features i'm looking for are enabled right?

Comment: Kernel modules need to be loaded to be shown by `lsmod`; to become loaded, kernel has to determine they're needed, or they've to be loaded manually. Ipsec modules might just need to be loaded through the configuration files. If you haven't used any app for ipsec management, they shouldn't be loaded and that's normal.

Comment: yesterday when i started my linux box it won't boot and show blank display. so i try recovery mode and reboot it again, it could boot from normal OS option but i have to do the same thing everytime i close this VBOX. beside that is it normal to have old and new kernel list on '/boot'? when i checked it again using 'ls /boot' it show both kernel lists, '2 initrd.img' and '2 vmlinu' etc...